# Find symlink using Find in Perl

Tags: perl, find, symlink

I have faced some issue on how to find a symlink inside a directory using Find library, it can't be found and I am very new in using Perl.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;
use File::Find;
use File::Copy;

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                            ->name( 'table.txt' )
                            ->in( '/a/b/c' );
for my $file (@files)   
{

    print "\nfile: $file\n";
```

Supposedly there is another directory that contain the specified file, table.txt, but it is a symlink that is /a/b/d, but the symlink is not there when it is printed out.

Comment: The docs suggest adding `extras({ follow => 1 })` to the chain of rules might be useful.

Comment: how can i add into the script? can you help me?

Comment: *"How can I add it to the script?"* Try `File::Find::Rule->file()->name( 'table.txt' )->extras({follow=>1})->in( '/a/b/c' )`

Comment: @Håkon If both link and target are in the same hierarchy (searched from above) then it runs into circularity and exits with error. If they aren't, then a direct search works.  Added to my answer.

Comment: my script work to find the file table.txt, under a parent directory i want, it searches all files with the same file name, the only it can't find, is the symlink directory, because Find could not detect it as a directory or a folder.

Comment: This is because it doesn't "follow" links. You can tell it to, but then If the link is in the same hierarchy as its target it will run into circular links and, fortunately, it is smart enough to detect that and it exits with an error. See a comment added to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) implements the [-X filetests](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html), as methods.  The one that tests whether an entry is a symlink (`-l`) is called `symlink`.

In my reading of the question you don't know the name of that directory (otherwise, why "find" a file in it?), except that it is a symbolic link. Then you need to first find directories which are symlinks, then find files in them. For this second task you'll need to tell the module to *follow* the links.

I use a test structure on disk

```
test_find/a/c/c.txt
test_find/a/b/b.txt
test_find/is_link  -> a/c  ("is_link" is a symbolic link to "a/c")
```

and from the directory right above it I run the program

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use File::Find::Rule;

my $top_dir = shift @ARGV || './test_find';

my @symlink_dirs = File::Find::Rule->directory->symlink->in($top_dir);

foreach my $dir (@symlink_dirs) {
    my @files = File::Find::Rule->file->extras({follow => 1})->in($dir);
    say "in $dir: @files";
}
```

which prints

```
in test_find/is_link: test_find/is_link/c.txt
```

Note that the program will find *all* files in *all* directories which are symlinks. Writing an explicit loop as above allows you to add code to decide which of the symlink-directories to actually search. If you don't mind looking through all of them you can just do

```
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file->extras({follow => 1})->in(@symlink_dirs);
```

See documentation for features to limit the search using what you know about the directory/file.

---

If the link directory is in a hierarchy not including the target, then simply search that hierarchy.

With test structure

```
other_hier/is_link  -> ../test_find/a/c
test_find/a/c/c.txt
```

you only need to tell it to follow the links

```
my @all_files = File::Find::Rule  # may use linebreaks and spaces
    -> file
    -> extras({ follow => 1 })
    -> in('other_hier');
```

When added to the above program and printed this adds

```
another/is_link/c.txt
```

You can of course replace the literal `'other_hier'` with `$top_dir` and invoke the program with argument `other_hier` (and make that `other_hier` directory and the link in it).

If both link and target are in the same hierarchy that is searched then you can't do this; the search would run into circular links (the module detects that and exits with error).

Comment: Will it work for the file that not in the symlink directory too?

Comment: @DanialHaris  This first finds all directories which _are_ symlinks, since in my understanding that is what you know about the directory (that it is a link), then it finds all files in _those_ directories.  For files in yet other directories you'd need a separate search. All of that can probably be bundled in one search but you didn't specify what you are looking for, apart for that one file in that link-directory.

Comment: From my script above, how can I loop each directory that it found including the symlink, to find, table.txt file, in a parent directory /a/ .

Comment: @DanialHaris (1) Your posted script is incomplete.  (2) The method `...->file->...` tells it to find files, not directories. So it will not return any directories.  This answer does both, finds directories and finds files, so you can see the difference.

Comment: oh, i get it, that's mean, i can't get directly the files in the symlink or is there a way for it?

Comment: @DanialHaris If the link-directory is in a hierarchy that _does not_ contain its target, then yes; I added that to the answer. Otherwise ... the files are already found in the target directory; why search its link? It's the same files.  (It actually runs into circular structures and exits with an error reporting that.)

Comment: Because I want it to automatically open the files and do something with it including the files in the link, which it have the same file name, table.txt

Comment: is there any way to open symlink directory and normal directory together?

Comment: @DanialHaris What do you mean by open them "_together_"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52439965/find-symbolic-link-and-directory-together-perl

Comment: @DanialHaris I don't understand what you need (I've read your new question).  But, as a guess: maybe you can make use of `->or(...)` in `File::Find::Rule`?

Comment: @DanialHaris  I think that I saw a comment here from you, saying that my comment on `->or` was useful, bu which is now gone.  If that indeed seems helpful let me know and I can add it to my answer.